# Converting image containing text to editable text

Tags: image

I have a pdf file that is scanned from a hard copy . Therefore the pdf file has an image of the hardcopy . Now when I try to convert the pdf into word , I dont get an editable document , rather I get an image sitting on the word document . Is there any way I can make a editable word document out of it ? Any Software program or something which will help me do that ?

Comment: It should be posted in [superuser ](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called optical character recognition OCR

There are lots of software packages that do this - to do this in a program try http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/